# How to paste numbers with a different separator in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I tried selecting the cells and setting their format as “Text, English (USA),” and set the language in the status bar to “English (USA)” as well, but when I paste [data from this page](http://www.gardeningplaces.com/articles/nutrition-per-hectare1.htm), e.g.

| Food | kcal per sq m |
| --- | --- |
| cassava | 1,940 |

LibreOffice Calc cuts off the trailing `0`:

[image: 1,940 turn into 1,94]

How can I get it to paste the full decimal value of `1,940` without the trailing `0` being cut off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, set the default cell locale to “English (USA)” via “Tools > Options > Languages > Locale setting:”

[image: Locale Setting English (USA)]

Then the values paste correctly:

[image: Correct Number value]

Answer (score 1):

Select the cells, then:

- Set the Number format to Number
- Set the decimal places to 0
- Check Thousands separator

[image: Cell Format]

Comment: Nice tip on the separator, but setting 0 decimal places leaves me with 2.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Even when you set the format as Number and not Text?

Comment: All cells are "Number", and "Text" has "Decimal places" disabled.